# Using react-native-wifi-reborn to do auto connect to wifi on android and ios with react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, permissions

I am making an app to control the device, I use react-native-wifi-reborn to connect to a hidden wifi, but when I call the connect function, the phone asks for permission to change wifi and I click allow, but after that, the permission request is repeated until the wifi connects wifi, the requesting permission stops.

How can I fix this error. Looking forward to everyone's help !. Thank you!

My english is not good, looking forward to your help!

i'm using:

react-native: 0.60.5,

react-native-wifi-reborn: 4.3.4,

Here is the picture asking for permission and the code you use to connect.

```
onPressChangeWifi = async() => {
    const checkpermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )
    if(!checkpermission){
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                title: 'Location permission is required for WiFi connections',
                message:
                    'This app needs location permission as this is required  ' +
                    'to scan for wifi networks.',
                buttonNegative: 'DENY',
                buttonPositive: 'ALLOW',
            },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            // You can now use react-native-wifi-reborn
            connectToWifi()
        } else {
            // Permission denied
        }
    }else{
        connectToWifi()
    }
}

const connectToWifi = () => {
    WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID('MarsWiFi4282', '123567890' , false).then(
        () => {
            console.warn("Connected successfully!");
        },
        () => {
            console.warn("Connection failed!");
        }
    );
    WifiManager.getCurrentWifiSSID().then(
    ssid => {
        console.warn("Your current connected wifi SSID is " + ssid);
    },
    () => {
        console.warn("Cannot get current SSID!");
    }
    );
}
```

[image]